# PHP option value from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck here for almost 2hours,  I'm new to scripting but cant fix this!
the  function won't show my category's he leaves it blanco

I've tried everything to get the row function in the value,

also wrote down in de script where the problem is

```
<?php

$query = (" SELECT * FROM category") or die(mysql_error());
$pak = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($pak);

 echo '
   <form action="post.php" method="post">
    Category: 
     <select name="cat">
     while($roz=mysql_fetch_array($row)) {


       <option value="'.$roz["nameID"].'">'.$roz["name"].'</option> // here is the problem

       }
     </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
 ';

?>
```

Comment: Should your PHP code really be part of the string that you're echoing? Any decent syntax-highlighting editor would have told you what the problem was.... even SO's syntax highlighting tells you

Comment: you're printing $roz["nameID"] but the variable that contains the results of the query is actually called $row.

Comment: also you're using the deprecated `mysql_` syntax instead of the much more secure and go-forward `mysqli_` syntax. there is a lot going on here that needs fixing.

Comment: @DiegoPino, the `$roz` variable is set in the while loop condition, though he does need to use $pak instead of $row in the fetch_array function.

Comment: use `echo $roz[0];` if it doesnt work implement your code as in this link: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#95881

Comment: `while($roz=mysql_fetch_array($pak)) {
     
      
       <option value="'.$roz["nameID"].'">'.$roz["name"].'</option> // here is the problem
       
       }
     </select>`
doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Frist of all:**

You should not use mysql_* functions. They are depracted and will eventually stop working. Look up mysqli_* or PDO instead.

**Second of all:** you have several syntax errors in your code.

**Try this instead:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM category";
$pak = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
//Removed mysql_fetch_array

 echo '
   <form action="post.php" method="post">
    Category: 
     <select name="cat">';

     while($roz=mysql_fetch_array($pak)) {   //added reference to mysql_query result instead of fetch_array;


       echo '<option value="'.$roz["nameID"].'">'.$roz["name"].'</option>';     
       }

    echo ' </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
   </form> ';
```

Comment: you are doing the same thing he is, including the while loop in the string

Comment: Yepp. I where editing (Now finished).

Comment: `<select name="cat">
  while($roz=mysql_fetch_array($row)) {
     
      
       <option value="'.$row["nameID"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option> // here is the problem
       
       }
     </select>`
It works now, but only he takes one single name id from database

Comment: What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: He only shows on nameid of the database not all

Comment: Are you sure the table "category" contains more then one reccord? The above code would output one option/row in table "category"

Comment: Yes i checked my database I've 3 category's

Comment: And you have changed while($roz=mysql_fetch_array($pak)) ... As pointed out above?

Comment: changed something, it works now thanks for you help

Comment: These is just on little problem I receive the nameID from database but now I need to put the nameID in another table which is called 'post' 
`<select name="cat" input="cat">';
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
echo '
       <option value="'.$row["nameID"].'" name="cat">'.$row["name"].'</option> // here is the problem
        '; }
      echo '
     </select>`

Comment: Seems like a new and different problem. Post a new question. (After you've tried to solve the problem your self). And mark this answer as correct aswell.